# Rails - link_to and button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my Rails 3.2.3 application I'm using Ajax and jQuery. There is a link on a page and I want to replace it with a button. The code below is working perfect

```
<%= link_to "More", {:controller => "home", :action => "test_method", :page=>@current_page }, :remote => true,:id => 'lnk_more' %>
```

But this one doesn't

```
<%= button_to "More", {:controller => "home", :action => "test_method", :page=>@current_page }, :remote => true,:id => 'lnk_more' %>
```

The result html for a link and for a button is here

```
#link
<a href="/home/test_method?page=1" data-remote="true" id="lnk_more" disabled="disabled">More </a>


#button
<form action="/home/test_method?page=1" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post"><div><input id="lnk_more" type="submit" value="More "><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="hFCuBR+88FYKEvNTZok+QRhxf6fHA+ucC6i2yc9hBEk="></div></form>
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= button_to "More", 
     { :controller => :home, :action=> :test_method, :page => @current_page}, 
     { :remote => true, :id => 'lnk_more' } 
 %>
```

will give an id to the input

```
<input id="lnk_more" type="submit" value="More">
```

Comment: @AlexMaslakov, the parameter in this context is the page

Answer (score 1):

You must change the method `:method=>:get`, since by default it is set to `post`. And your routes are probably not routing it correctly

`<%= button_to "More", {:controller => "home", :action => "test_method", :page=>@current_page }, :method=>:get, :remote => true,:id => 'lnk_more' %>`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the `remote` option should be part of `options`. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to